# vue3) Google Login Api (GSI)'s redirect mode can't find http://localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I want to adjust google login api(GSI) redirect mode. If api complecated, redirect the url to "http://localhost:3000/oauth", post credential token to backend and redirect to "http://localhost:3000".

Here is my code.

```
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        :data-client_id="googleClientId"
        data-ux_mode="redirect"
        data-auto_prompt="false"
        :data-callback="getGoogleLoginCallback"
        style="z-index: 100000000000000000"
      ></div>
      <div class="g_id_signin"></div>
```

After the page redirected and i clicked my account, i got the error http://localhost:3000 is
[image]

How can i get page?

I can't find anything method to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-login_uri) you can can see that if you doesn't provide data-login_uri attribute, google will redirect to same page where you clicked the login button, if you are planing to post the credintial JWT after login to `http://localhost:3000/oauth` then the html must be like this

```html
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        :data-client_id="googleClientId"
        data-ux_mode="redirect"
        data-auto_prompt="false"
        data-login_uri="http://localhost:3000/oauth"
        :data-callback="getGoogleLoginCallback"
        style="z-index: 100000000000000000"
      ></div>
      <div class="g_id_signin"></div>
```

I am not recommending this way of using html in your Vue app, this may not work if the component containing this html is mounted after the [library](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/load-3p-authorization-library) is loaded

### Instead Use renderButton function

Instead you can use [google.accounts.id.renderButton](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.renderButton) function to dynamically create a Login Button.

### Or Use a Plugin Instead

You can easily do the same using this Vue 3 plugin [vue3-google-login](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/) which I recently created for easily integrating Login With Google feature in your Vue 3 application, all you need to do is [initialise the plugin in main.js](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/#initialize-the-plugin) with your client id then use the component `GoogleLogin` like this

```
<script setup>
const idConfiguration = {
      login_uri:'http://localhost:3000/oauth',
      ux_mode:'redirect'
    }
</script>

<template>
    <GoogleLogin 
    :idConfiguration="idConfiguration"
    />
</template>
```